# Exception has occurred: TypeError object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to execute this code

```
import pandas as pd

df_schema = pd.read_csv('survey_results_schema.csv')
df_results = pd.read_csv('survey_results_public.csv', index_col='Respondent')

print(df_results['Country'].apply(len))
```

And I should get this:

```
Respondent
1                14
2                22
3                8
       ...
```

But I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
object of type 'float' has no len()
```

If we execute this line`print(df_results['Country'])`, we'll get this

```
Respondent
1                United Kingdom
2        Bosnia and Herzegovina
3                      Thailand
4                 United States
5                       Ukraine
              ...
88377                    Canada
88601                       NaN
88802                       NaN
88816                       NaN
88863                     Spain
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: how it is suppose to work use lambda inside apply try your self!

Comment: You are expecting all the rows in `df_results` to be populated, we can see from the final code block that there are missing values (`NaN`) on some rows. You need to work out what to do with them. A good starting point is here: [working with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

Comment: @BhavyaParikh using a lambda will not solve the issue here and you can apply `len` without using lambda. The issue is that `NaN` is float, which doesn't have a length.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think should be the result of `len(NaN)`? Why? What do you think `NaN` is, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you have NaN in your data.
NaN type is recognized as a float so this is the reason for your error.

The following code will set 0 for every NaN  value else will set the len of the value:

```
print(df_results['Country'].apply(lambda x: 0 if pd.isna(x) else len(x)))
```

A better approach will be to clear your null values before working with the Dataframe.
You can use the dropna function for that:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna